# How can I scrape "Net Worth" from YieldWatch?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I would to scrape a website as per following:

1. Go to [Yieldwatch](https://www.yieldwatch.net/)
2. Enter `0xF54274757Bf717B1ab52bA0d3a7CbF635f856a0d` into the Address textbox and click the binoculars
3. Scrape the text under "Net worth" [image]

I am using Selenium in Python to try and do it and here is my attempt so far:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Safari  # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://www.yieldwatch.net/'
bsc_public_key = '0xF54274757Bf717B1ab52bA0d3a7CbF635f856a0d'

# with closing(Safari()) as browser:
browser = Safari()
browser.get(url)

textbox = browser.find_element_by_id('addressInputField')
textbox.clear()
textbox.send_keys(bsc_public_key)

button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('binoculars icon')
button.click()

# # wait for the page to load
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=20).until(
    lambda x: x.find_element_by_id('ui centered image'))

# store it to string variable
page_source = browser.page_source
print(page_source)
```

The code doesn't work.  After the browser loads, I don't see the textbox filled in with the address.  How can I do this in Python (with or without Selenium)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need the heavy guns of `selenium`. You can get all the data from the API endpoint.

Here's how:

```
import requests

wallet = "0xF54274757Bf717B1ab52bA0d3a7CbF635f856a0d"
endpoint = f"https://www.yieldwatch.net/api/all/{wallet}?platforms=beefy,pancake,hyperjump,auto,mdex"

wallet_data = requests.get(endpoint).json()["result"]

# https://yieldwatch.medium.com/yieldwatch-faqs-93c2cde244bf
# Net Value = Total Deposit + Total Yield + Wallet Balance — Total Debt
total = sum(v["totalUSDValues"]["total"] for v in wallet_data["PancakeSwap"].values())
net_worth = total + wallet_data["walletBalance"]["totalUSDValue"]
print(f"Net worth for {wallet}:\n{round(net_worth, 2)}")
```

This outputs most up-to-date net worth:

```
Net worth for 0xF54274757Bf717B1ab52bA0d3a7CbF635f856a0d:
2213.13
```

Note: The [FAQ](https://yieldwatch.medium.com/yieldwatch-faqs-93c2cde244bf) says you need `Total Debt` to calculate the net worth but this wallet doesn't have any debt so I didn't include the value in the equation.

However, if you have a wallet that has a debt, please share it, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Really nice! How did you figure out how the API worked?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the `ui centered image` element text when it is still not presenting the final value.
Try waiting for `invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='content']//div[@class='header']")`
And only after that read the text from `ui centered image` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver import Safari
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

url = 'https://www.yieldwatch.net/'
address = input('Enter Your Wallet Address : ')
browser = Safari()
browser.get(url)

btnpancake = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='root']/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/img")
btnpancake.click()

wallet = browser.find_element(By.ID, "addressInputField")
wallet.clear()
wallet.send_keys(address)

send = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='root']/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[1]")
send.click()

time.sleep(7)

pool = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='root']/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h4/div[2]")
poolval = pool.text
value = poolval.split(' ')
print(f"Current Pool : {value[0]}")
print(f"Total Cake Value : {value[2]}")

earn = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='root']/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
earnval = earn.text
value2 = earnval.split(' ')
print(f"Total Cake : {value2[0]}")
print(f"Pending {value2[3]} : {value2[2]}")
print(f"Harvest : {value2[4]+' '+value2[5]}")

totalyield = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='root']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/span/span")
totalyieldval = totalyield.text
print(f"Total Yield : {totalyieldval}")

apr = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='root']/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/h4/div")
aprval = apr.text
print(f"APR : {aprval}")

browser.quit()
```